# How can we index the keys from nested array of objects to our input set post data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to set course attribute from parameter to my input so that I can be able the insert the value on it but I cannot access the course attribute. ends_level and course becomes any instead of string means I haven't indexed properly the ends_level which the array of object course. I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. I hope I have explained it well. Thanks in advance y'all.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateProfile } from '../../../actions/profile';

const Profile = ({ data }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const currentId = data._id;
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState(
        {
            profile: {
                name: "",
            },
            skills: [
                {
                    end: "",
                    ends_level: [
                        {
                            course: "",
                            level: ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ],
                
        }
    );

    const profile = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.profile.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(profile) setPostData(profile);
    }, [profile])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId) {
            dispatch(updateProfile(currentId, postData));
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
        <TextField
        value={postData.profile.name}
        onChange={(e) => 
            setPostData(
                {
                    ...postData, profile:
                    {
                        ...postData.profile, name: e.target.value
                    } 
                }
            )
        }
        />

        <TextField
        onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData(
                {
                    ...postData, skills:
                    {
                        ...postData.skills, ends_level:
                            {
                                ...postData.skills.ends_level, course: e.target.value
                            }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        />
        
        <Button variant="primary" size="md" type="submit" block >Save</Button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: I feel like you're using new objects with spread operators to spread objects into positions where you originally had arrays, thereby merging your arrays out of existence.

Comment: @Atmas Hi, please add your answer

Comment: On the initial state for postData, you defined "skills" as an array, whereas in your change handler, you are treating it as an object.

Comment: Ok. I will add that as an answer in a more full sense when I get to a keyboard. Was that the main issue for you?

Comment: Ok. Added answer. There is an unresolved plurality question to sort through though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you are using spread operators to spread objects into positions where you originally had arrays. Also when trying to sort out an answer, I feel like you aren't addressing a plurality problem with these arrays. Namely, you have a single target value which may apply to an array full of skills and an array full of ends_levels in each skill, so you have to decide how/what you want the new changed to value to apply to.

Here is a good start, with TypeScript enhancements, that lays out the schema and attempts to craft a new "post data" object which looks like the old one. You will have to fill out the commented section below to affect the array(s) with the new value as you see fit.

```
interface SkillType {
    end: string,
    ends_level: [
        {
            course: string,
            level: string
        }
    ]
}

interface DataType {
    profile: {
        name: string
    },
    skills: SkillType[]
}

let postData: DataType = {
    profile: {
        name: "",
    },
    skills: [
        {
            end: "",
            ends_level: [
                {
                    course: "",
                    level: ""
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
};

// Create a new holder with all the old skills
let newSkills : SkillType[] = [... postData.skills ];

// Will have multiple skills per post-data
// Each post-data will have multiple "ends_levels" in it
// Do you want to merge it so all of these blocks now have the new value e.target.value ??
// If so, manipulate newSkills

let newPostData: DataType = {
    ...postData,
    skills: newSkills
}
```